# I can't see usage in google cloud endpoints v2

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have a project using something like 20 endpoints.
I had migrated to endpoints v2 and java8 as described in the docs.

I have also generated some API key, but when I call the endpoints it works, but I don't have any stats in the endpoints console.

I've also correctly deployed the openapi configuration in google cloud

here is an example of an endpoint configuration:

```
@Api(
    name = "editorialContentApi",
    version = "v1",
    resource = "editorialContent",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
        ownerDomain = "edito.contents.backend.xxxx.com",
        ownerName = "edito.contents.backend.xxxx.com"
    )
)
```

this code is called using the ?key parameter

The endpoints are deployed on google app engine, billing is enabled on this project. 
Has anyone a clue on this?

Comment: If you make a request without an API key, then I think your app is misconfigured. Can you post your web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just forgot to add the filters needed to enable API management and logs described here :https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management

sorry.